# position fixed, css, ul

Tags: html, css, position

я решил сделать фиксацию `ul`, но у меня ничего не работает, ссылки как были не зафиксированы, так и остались.

```css
.collection_num {
  position: fixed;
}

ul.collection_num {
  margin-top: 50vh;
}

ul.collection_num li {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

.collection_num_fixed {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="collection">
  <div class="collection_number">
    <div class="collection_num_fixed">
      <ul class="collection_num">
        <li>Коллекция 1</li>
        <li>Коллекция 2</li>
        <li>Коллекция 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="collection_photo" data-section-name="homef">
      <img src="img/collections/gal_img_002.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="collection_photo" data-section-name="home">
      <img src="img/collections/gal_img_002.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: какие ссылки, пункты списка `li`? вроде зафиксированы https://jsfiddle.net/peqd2qpc/

Comment: Там будут якоря, вот ссылка http://catalogue.woodstock.org.ua/collection.html

Comment: Замени margin-top: 50vh; на top: 50vh; ну или просто допиши top: 0;

Comment: Всё зафиксировано.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.collection {
  position: relative;
}

.collection_num_fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}

ul.collection_num li {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.collection_photo {
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
  display: block;
  // высота равна высоте меню
}

.collection_photo img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="collection">
  <div class="collection_num_fixed">
    <ul class="collection_num">
      <li>Коллекция 1</li>
      <li>Коллекция 2</li>
      <li>Коллекция 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="collection_photo">
    <img src="http://html.com/wp-content/uploads/very-large-flamingo.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```